# Highcharts column chart. Sometimes unusable 1px stacked columns. Sometimes usable side by side columns

Tags: highcharts

I have a basic column chart.  With smaller data sets, the chart displays as it should.  See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmg0y2a3/1/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



Highcharts.chart('container', {
    "chart": {
        "type": "column"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "High Net Income"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "tickInterval": 604800000,
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
            "millisecond": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "second": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "minute": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "hour": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "day": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "week": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "month": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "year": "%m/%d/%Y"
        },
        "labels": {
            "rotation": -45
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "Audience Reach"
        }
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "pointPadding": 0.2
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "Distribution Count",
        "data": [
            [1504342376000, 6403],
            [1504423639000, 1086],
            [1504510033000, 1089]
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Unique VELO Count",
        "data": [
            [1504342376000, 2973],
            [1504423639000, 597],
            [1504510033000, 599]
        ]
    }]
});
```

I like that it's displaying each series side by side for a specific date.

However, when the data sets get larger, I get skinny little stacked 1px columns and I don't like it one bit, but I don't know what I need to do to keep the columns side by side, not stacked, and have a width that is usable.  See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmg0y2a3/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
```

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    "chart": {
        "type": "column"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "High Net Income"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "tickInterval": 604800000,
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
            "millisecond": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "second": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "minute": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "hour": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "day": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "week": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "month": "%m/%d/%Y",
            "year": "%m/%d/%Y"
        },
        "labels": {
            "rotation": -45
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "Audience Reach"
        }
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "pointPadding": 0.2
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "Distribution Count",
        "data": [
            [1504342376000, 6403],
            [1504423639000, 1086],
            [1504510033000, 1089],
            [1504597165000, 1103],
            [1504683776000, 1099],
            [1504770376000, 1210],
            [1504858167000, 1242],
            [1504942932000, 1224],
            [1505027910000, 1227],
            [1505114658000, 1229],
            [1505201998000, 1214],
            [1505289935000, 1110],
            [1505289941000, 1110],
            [1505418941000, 930],
            [1505419065000, 930]
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Unique VELO Count",
        "data": [
            [1504342376000, 2973],
            [1504423639000, 597],
            [1504510033000, 599],
            [1504597165000, 598],
            [1504683776000, 590],
            [1504770376000, 637],
            [1504858167000, 636],
            [1504942932000, 625],
            [1505027910000, 628],
            [1505114658000, 639],
            [1505201998000, 638],
            [1505289935000, 617],
            [1505289941000, 617],
            [1505418941000, 557],
            [1505419065000, 557]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set static pointWidth:  for series object in plotOptions, like below:

```
"plotOptions": {
    "series": {
        "pointWidth": 15
    },
},
```

API Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.pointWidth

Live working: http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/qetr9p0p/

Best regards!

Comment: I did this, but if there are only one or two data points the point width is skinny and doesn't fill the chart.  What would be best is a minPointWidth that you could set, but it doesn't seem to exist.  I guess I could conditionally check the data length and set the point width dynamically, but I'd rather Highcharts handle this in a usable way.

Comment: Also... The columns are still stacked when setting the pointWidth.  I do not want them stacked, I want them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

The dates in the series were the issue.  If I mutate the dates by setting to UTC and truncating to the day, the bars will not stack and they will not be 1px wide if there is over 12 points of data:

```
time_series = broadcast_data.time_series_data[b];
date = new Date(time_series.broadcast_dt);
date = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());
```